# How to set a primary key min value in Django

Tags: django

Suppose I have a model which has a primary key and I don't want they primary key to start from 1. Is there a way that I can specify an initial value of a primary key?

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    primary_field = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'mymodel_seq'

def new_seq_number():
    mymodel_seq = MyModel.objects.raw("select primary_field, nextval('mymodel_seq') from mymodel_seq")[0]
    seq_number = u'%04i' % mymodel_seq.nextval
    return seq_number
```

Comment: Thanks, just wonder where I can use the new_seq_number function?

Comment: just call it as extension property of your model everytime you save